# ‘getGlobalContext’ was not declared in this scope llvm static LLVMContext &Context = getGlobalContext();

Tags: gcc, llvm

I was trying to build **dragonegg** plugin from the document inside the package but after running the command below:

```
GCC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.6 make
```

the output was :

```
error:‘getGlobalContext’ was not declared in this scope static LLVMContext &Context = getGlobalContext();
```

I've installed all the libraries it needs and checked different version of gcc but the the result was the same.
Is there anyway to solve the problem?

Comment: Try older LLVM version. getGlobalContext is gone in 3.9